# Can I implement this newtype as a composition of other types?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, type-theory, type-kinds, polykinds

I've written a newtype `Const3` that's very similar to `Const`, but contains the first of three given type arguments:

```
newtype Const3 a b c = Const3 { getConst3 :: a }
```

I can define very many useful instances for this newtype, but I'd have to do it all myself.

However, the function I'm applying on the type level resembles the function

```
\a b c -> a
```

which `@pl` tells me is equivalent to `const . const`.

Both `(.)` and `const` have matching newtype wrappers: [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) and [`Const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const). So I figured I'd be able to write:

```
type Const3 = Compose Const Const
```

And inherit useful instances automatically, such as:

```
instance Functor (Const m)
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g)
-- a free Functor instance for Const3!
```

But GHC disagrees:

```
const3.hs:5:23:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Const’
    The first argument of ‘Compose’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘Const’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    In the type ‘Compose Const Const’
    In the type declaration for ‘Const3’
```

This seems to be related to the kinds of `Compose` and `Const`:

```
*Main> :k Compose
Compose :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
*Main> :k Const
Const :: * -> * -> *
```

So after a little bit of searching, I found that there's a GHC extension called `PolyKinds` that allows me to do something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
newtype Const a b = Const { getConst :: a }
```

And as if by magic the kinds are right:

```
 *Main> :k Compose
 Compose :: (k -> *) -> (k1 -> k) -> k1 -> *
 *Main> :k Const
 Const :: * -> k -> *
```

But I *still* can't compose them to write `Const3 = Compose Const Const`.

```
const3.hs:12:23:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Const’
    The first argument of ‘Compose’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘Const’ has kind ‘* -> k0 -> *’
    In the type ‘Compose Const Const’
    In the type declaration for ‘Const3’
```

What gives? Is there some clever way to do this, so I can reap the benefits of inheriting the `Functor` etc. instances from `Const` and `Compose`?

> (As a side note, the original thought that led me to `Const3` was writing:
>
> ```
> newtype Const3 a b c = Const3 { getConst3 :: a }
>
> instance Monoid m => Category (Const3 m) where
>   id = Const3 mempty
>   Const3 x . Const3 y = Const3 (mappend x y)
> ```
>
> capturing the idea that a *monoid is a single-object category*. It would be nice if there's a solution that still allows me to write the above instance somehow.)

Comment: `type Const3 a b c = Compose (Const a) (Const b) c` ? As the `but ‘Const’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’` message implies, you need to supply one type to the type constructor to arrive at the kind expected by `Compose`.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that's confusing—or, at least, the thing that confused *me*—is that `*` acts like a *concrete type*, not a type variable. So without `PolyKinds`, `Compose` has a type that's more like:

```
compose :: (A -> A) -> (A -> A) -> A -> A
```

Crucially, we can't replace an `A` with `A -> A` because they'd be different types, so, by the same logic, we can't replace `*` with `* -> *` either.

Even with `PolyKinds`, the kinds still aren't right. In particular, `Compose` expects `(k -> *)` as its first argument and you're trying to give it `(k -> (k2 -> *))`.

The reason you're forced to return a `*` kind is because you're using `newtypes`, and newtypes have to return a concrete type (ie of kind `*`). I tried to overcome this by turning `Compose` into a type synonym which finally had exactly the kind we want (with `PolyKinds`):

```
type Compose f g a = (f (g a))

λ> :k Compose
Compose :: (k1 -> k) -> (k2 -> k1) -> k2 -> k
```

However, using this still gave me a similar error, and I'm not certain if we can get it to work properly. The problem arose because applying `Compose` to the first `Const` gives us a kind with a `*` in it, probably because on limitations of type aliases like this:

```
λ> :k Compose Const
Compose Const :: (k -> *) -> k -> k1 -> *
```

Comment: I think it's `Const` that's the hardest problem here, not `Compose`. Specifically, in the wanted expansion `Const (Const a) b c`, the first `Const` needs to have kind `(* -> *) -> * -> * -> *` and the second needs to have kind `* -> * -> *`, different number of arguments, so they cannot be a common `newtype` either.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Oh, good point. But making `Const` a type synonym doesn't really do what we want...

Comment: Interestingly, if you make both `Const` and `Compose` kind-polymorphic enough, you can get GHCi's `:kind` to show the correct kind, e.g. `Compose Const Const Int Bool String :: *`, but it still doesn't work as a type annotation: "Type synonym `Const` should have 4 arguments, but has been given 2 in the expression: `42 :: Compose Const Const Int Bool String`"

Comment: @Cactus That works if you enable [`LiberalTypeSynonyms`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#type-synonyms), which expands everything as far as possible before checking number of arguments. Alas, all this is still useless for OP's goal of defining *instances* for the partially applied type synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

From the other answers, it seems like it's not that easy, however if the only thing you want to have are the "free" instances, one quick way is using a `newtype` over the regular `Const` with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
module ConstThree (Const3,pattern Const3,getConst3) where
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

newtype Const3 a b c = MkConst3 (Const a c) deriving (Functor,Applicative,Foldable,Traversable,Eq,Ord,Show,Monoid)

pattern Const3 :: a -> Const3 a b c
pattern Const3 x = MkConst3 (Const x)

getConst3 :: Const3 a b c -> a
getConst3 (Const3 x) = x
```

In the above, I'm also using `PatternSynonyms` to hide the internal use of `Const` from clients.

This is what you get:

```
λ> :t Const3
Const3 :: a -> Const3 a b c
λ> :t getConst3
getConst3 :: Const3 a b c -> a
λ> :i Const3
pattern Const3 :: a -> Const3 a b c
        -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:13:5

type role Const3 representational phantom phantom
newtype Const3 a b c = MkConst3 (Const a c)
        -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:5
instance Eq a => Eq (Const3 a b c)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:100
instance Functor (Const3 a b)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:59
instance Ord a => Ord (Const3 a b c)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:103
instance Show a => Show (Const3 a b c)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:107
instance Monoid a => Applicative (Const3 a b)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:67
instance Foldable (Const3 a b)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:79
instance Traversable (Const3 a b)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:88
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Const3 a b c)
  -- Defined at /tmp/alpha-dbcdf.hs:10:112
```

And as expected you can do:

```
instance Monoid m => Category (Const3 m) where
  id = Const3 mempty
  Const3 x . Const3 y = Const3 (mappend x y)
```